# Convert to Mhz in java/Android

Tags: java, android, type-conversion, frequency

I found this code to get Cpu freq. in Android:

```
private String ReadCPUMhz()
        {
             ProcessBuilder cmd;
             String result="";
             int resultshow = 0;

             try{
              String[] args = {"/system/bin/cat", "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq"};
              cmd = new ProcessBuilder(args);

              Process process = cmd.start();
              InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
              byte[] re = new byte[1024];
              while(in.read(re) != -1)
               {
                 result = result + new String(re);

               }

              in.close();
             } catch(IOException ex){
              ex.printStackTrace();
             }
             return result;
        }
```

The problem is that the result is in Khz and not Mhz so i get something like: `300000`.. How can i convert in Mhz? A user wrote time ago that it found the solution using: `result.trim()` 
as you can see here [Convert khz value from CPU into mhz or ghz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540383/convert-khz-value-from-cpu-into-mhz-or-ghz) but he doesn't explain how use it.. Anyone knows? Thanks

Comment: Don't you just need to divide by 1000 ?

Comment: Do you mean `result/1000`? If possible i wuould show also 1 or 2 decimals.. Something like `400,2` Mhz for example.. I don't know if you understand

Comment: return String.format("%.02f Mhz", Integer.parseInt(result)/1000f);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the post you mentioned, the error

```
invalid int: "192000 "
```

is indeed avoided by using String.trim() before calling

```
Integer.parseInt(result);
```

Because in the String "192000 ", there is an extra space at the end that needs to be removed. The method trim() of class String removes leading and trailing whitespace:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29

So, based on your example code:

```
/* replace XXXX by the name of the
   class that holds method `ReadCPUMhz()`
*/
XXX instance = new XXX(); // supposing class XXX has such a constructor
String result = instance.ReadCPUMhz().trim(); // removes leading & trailing spaces
int kHzValue = Integer.parseInt(result); // result in kHz
int MHzResult = kHzValue / 1000; // result in MHz
```

should give the expected result in MHz.

Answer (score 0):

Divide your result in Khz/1000 to get Mhz. Check this answer for the decimals thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10959430/2065418

```
tv.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(i2));
```